# AWSUserPoolsSignIn refresh token iOS

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios

I am using the swift package AWSiOSSDKV2 from `https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios-spm`

I can log in using the SDK but how can I use refresh Token to generate new accessToken using their SDK?

```
func login() {

        let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: PortalUserConfig.POOL_NAME)

        if let user = pool?.getUser() {
            
            user.getSession(username, password: password, validationData: nil).continueWith(block: { task -> Any? in
                if let error = task.error {
                    let errorMessage = (error as NSError).userInfo["message"] as? String
                } else {
                    
                    guard let accessToken = task.result?.accessToken else {
                        return nil
                    }
                    print(accessToken)
                    let refreshToken = task.result?.refreshToken
                    print(refreshToken)
  
                }
                return nil
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Amplify library will [automatically fetch](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/auth/how-it-works/q/platform/ios/#token-fetch-and-refresh) new id and access tokens if they have expired and the refresh token is still valid. You can adjust the lifetime of your refresh tokens [in the settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html) for your User Pool client. To learn more about OAuth token lifetime strategies, you can read up on the options [over at OAuth.com](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/).